Odoo v16 - Inconsistent loading of CSS on reports
We are experiencing some inconsistent loading of CSS on an Odoo database hosted on Odoo.sh. When sending invoices in bulk the CSS randomly fails to load for a few invoices and then loads fine again after a while. During a bulk process of invoices I tracked down that the URL of the web.report_assets_common.min.css switch on 12:05:22 resulting in a 404 when requesting the old URL. It seems that Odoo keeps requesting the old URL while generating the invoice PDFs but after a while yet another URL is used and the CSS is loaded again in the PDF report.
...
[28/May/2024
12:05:16]
"GET /web/assets/227768-c5247d9/web.report_assets_common.min.css HTTP/1.0" 200
- 4 0.001 0.004
[28/May/2024 12:05:19]
"GET /web/assets/227768-c5247d9/web.report_assets_common.min.css HTTP/1.0" 200 - 4 0.001 0.004
[28/May/2024 12:05:22]
"GET
/web/assets/227861-45bea67/web.report_assets_common.min.css HTTP/1.0" 200 - 9 0.004 0.008
[28/May/2024
12:05:227
"GET /web/assets/227768-c5247d9/web.report_assets_common.min.css HTTP/1.0" 404 - 9 0.007 0.005
[28/May/2024
12:05:231
"GET /web/assets/227768-c5247d9/web.report_assets_common.min.css HTTP/1.0" 404 - 2 0.000 0.003
[28/May/2024
12:05:25]
....
[28/May/2024
12:09:34]
"GET /web/assets/227768-c5247d9/web.report_assets_common.min.css HTTP/1.0" 404 - 3 0.001 0.003
128/May/2024
12:09:571
"GET /web/assets/227998-c5247d9/web.report_assets_common.min.css HTTP/1.0" 200 - 8 0.003 0.005
[28/May/2024
12:09:571
"GET /web/assets/227768-c5247d9/web.report_assets_common.min.css HTTP/1.0" 404 - 8 0.004 0.005
[28/May/2024
12:09:587
"GET /web/assets/227768-c5247d9/web.report_assets_common.min.css HTTP/1.0" 404 -
3 0.001 0.003
[28/May/2024
12:10:52]
"GET /web/assets/227998-c5247d9/web.report_assets_common.min.css HTTP/1.0" 200
- 4 0.001
0.007

This is the raw logs around the time the URL is switched.
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/stock.picking/read HTTP/1.0" 200 - 54 0.030 0.022
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/stock.move/read HTTP/1.0" 200 - 25 0.013 0.020
odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: The PDF documents 'VF_2024_07050.pdf' are now saved in the database
odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: The PDF report has been generated for model: account.move, records [86727].
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/studio.approval.rule/get_approval_spec HTTP/1.0" 200 - 12 0.006 0.008
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "POST /mail/thread/messages HTTP/1.0" 200 - 26 0.013 0.010
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "POST /mail/thread/data HTTP/1.0" 200 - 12 0.020 0.013
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/iot.device/search_read HTTP/1.0" 200 - 3 0.002 0.005
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/iot.device/search_read HTTP/1.0" 200 - 3 0.002 0.007
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "GET /web/assets/176874-d6fa3f9/web.report_assets_pdf.min.css HTTP/1.0" 200 - 4 0.001 0.004
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "GET /web/assets/227768-c5247d9/web.report_assets_common.min.css HTTP/1.0" 200 - 4 0.001 0.004
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "GET /base/static/img/bg_background_template.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.001
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "GET /web/static/fonts/lato/Lato-Bla-webfont.woff HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.001
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/iot.device/search_read HTTP/1.0" 200 - 3 0.002 0.006
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "GET /web/static/fonts/lato/Lato-Bol-webfont.woff HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.002
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "GET /web/static/fonts/lato/Lato-Lig-webfont.woff HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.001
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "GET /web/static/fonts/lato/Lato-Reg-webfont.woff HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.002
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "GET /web/static/fonts/lato/Lato-Hai-webfont.woff HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.001
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "GET /web/static/fonts/lato/Lato-RegIta-webfont.woff HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.001
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "GET /web/static/fonts/lato/Lato-LigIta-webfont.woff HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.002
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "GET /web/static/fonts/lato/Lato-HaiIta-webfont.woff HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.002
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "GET /web/static/fonts/lato/Lato-BolIta-webfont.woff HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.002
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "GET /web/static/fonts/lato/Lato-BlaIta-webfont.woff HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.002
[28/May/2024 12:05:19] "POST /web/action/load HTTP/1.0" 200 - 12 0.005 0.006
[28/May/2024 12:05:20] "GET /prijsstijgingen HTTP/1.0" 200 - 7 0.004 0.011
[28/May/2024 12:05:21] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/sale.order/web_search_read HTTP/1.0" 200 - 26 0.030 0.085
[28/May/2024 12:05:21] "POST /websocket/update_bus_presence HTTP/1.1" 200 - 12 0.005 0.031
[28/May/2024 12:05:21] "POST /websocket/peek_notifications HTTP/1.1" 200 - 9 0.003 0.005
[28/May/2024 12:05:21] "POST /sales/sale_quotation_onboarding_panel HTTP/1.0" 200 - 1 0.000 0.003
[28/May/2024 12:05:21] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/iot.device/search_read HTTP/1.0" 200 - 3 0.002 0.005
odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: The PDF documents 'VF_2024_07052.pdf' are now saved in the database
odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: The PDF report has been generated for model: account.move, records [86869].
[28/May/2024 12:05:22] "GET /web/assets/176874-d6fa3f9/web.report_assets_pdf.min.css HTTP/1.0" 200 - 4 0.002 0.006
[28/May/2024 12:05:22] "GET /web/assets/176874-d6fa3f9/web.report_assets_pdf.min.css HTTP/1.0" 200 - 5 0.002 0.006
[28/May/2024 12:05:22] "GET /web/assets/227861-45bea67/web.report_assets_common.min.css HTTP/1.0" 200 - 9 0.004 0.008
[28/May/2024 12:05:22] "GET /web/assets/227768-c5247d9/web.report_assets_common.min.css HTTP/1.0" 404 - 9 0.007 0.005
[28/May/2024 12:05:22] "GET /base/static/img/bg_background_template.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.001
[28/May/2024 12:05:22] "GET /base/static/img/bg_background_template.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.001
[28/May/2024 12:05:22] "GET /web/static/fonts/lato/Lato-Reg-webfont.woff HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.001
[28/May/2024 12:05:22] "GET /web/static/fonts/lato/Lato-Lig-webfont.woff HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.001
[28/May/2024 12:05:22] "GET /web/static/fonts/lato/Lato-Hai-webfont.woff HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.001
[28/May/2024 12:05:22] "GET /web/static/fonts/lato/Lato-Bol-webfont.woff HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.001
[28/May/2024 12:05:22] "GET /web/static/fonts/lato/Lato-Bla-webfont.woff HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0 0.000 0.001
[28/May/2024 12:05:22] "POST /web/action/load HTTP/1.0" 200 - 15 0.007 0.010
[28/May/2024 12:05:22] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/purchase.order/get_views HTTP/1.0" 200 - 103 0.035 0.059
[28/May/2024 12:05:22] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/purchase.order/web_search_read HTTP/1.0" 200 - 11 0.008 0.025
[28/May/2024 12:05:23] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/purchase.order/retrieve_dashboard HTTP/1.0" 200 - 16 0.011 0.007
[28/May/2024 12:05:23] "GET /web/assets/171950-c640072/1/web.assets_frontend_minimal.min.js HTTP/1.0" 200 - 4 0.001 0.004
[28/May/2024 12:05:23] "GET /web/image/res.users/12/avatar_128 HTTP/1.0" 304 - 13 0.006 0.009
[28/May/2024 12:05:23] "GET /web/image/res.users/6/avatar_128 HTTP/1.0" 304 - 22 0.009 0.014
[28/May/2024 12:05:23] "GET /web/assets/227768-c5247d9/web.report_assets_common.min.css HTTP/1.0" 404 - 2 0.000 0.003
[28/May/2024 12:05:23] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/iot.device/search_read HTTP/1.0" 200 - 16 0.008 0.007
[28/May/2024 12:05:23] "POST /websocket/update_bus_presence HTTP/1.1" 200 - 12 0.006 0.025
[28/May/2024 12:05:23] "POST /websocket/peek_notifications HTTP/1.1" 200 - 9 0.002 0.005
[28/May/2024 12:05:23] "POST /websocket/peek_notifications HTTP/1.1" 200 - 8 0.003 0.007
[28/May/2024 12:05:24] "GET /shop/0000-4164-duco-co2-regelklep-30m3-u-focus-238952?category=249&order=list_price+desc HTTP/1.0" 200 - 76 0.026 0.06│
[28/May/2024 12:05:24] "POST /websocket/update_bus_presence HTTP/1.1" 200 - 11 0.006 0.025
[28/May/2024 12:05:24] "POST /websocket/peek_notifications HTTP/1.1" 200 - 8 0.003 0.005
[28/May/2024 12:05:24] "POST /websocket/update_bus_presence HTTP/1.1" 200 - 11 0.006 0.024
[28/May/2024 12:05:24] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/iot.device/search_read HTTP/1.0" 200 - 3 0.002 0.005
[28/May/2024 12:05:24] "POST /websocket/peek_notifications HTTP/1.1" 200 - 8 0.003 0.007
[28/May/2024 12:05:24] "POST /websocket/update_bus_presence HTTP/1.1" 200 - 27 0.011 0.027
[28/May/2024 12:05:24] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/iot.device/search_read HTTP/1.0" 200 - 12 0.005 0.012
[28/May/2024 12:05:24] "POST /websocket/peek_notifications HTTP/1.1" 200 - 8 0.003 0.005
[28/May/2024 12:05:24] "POST /websocket/update_bus_presence HTTP/1.1" 200 - 12 0.006 0.025
[28/May/2024 12:05:24] "POST /websocket/peek_notifications HTTP/1.1" 200 - 9 0.003 0.005
[28/May/2024 12:05:24] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/sale.order/web_search_read HTTP/1.0" 200 - 31 0.037 0.060
[28/May/2024 12:05:24] "POST /websocket/update_bus_presence HTTP/1.1" 200 - 21 0.009 0.025
[28/May/2024 12:05:24] "POST /websocket/peek_notifications HTTP/1.1" 200 - 8 0.003 0.006
odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: wkhtmltopdf: Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError
[28/May/2024 12:05:24] "POST /websocket/peek_notifications HTTP/1.1" 200 - 9 0.006 0.006
odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: The PDF report has been generated for model: account.move, records [86977].
odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: The PDF report has been generated for model: stock.picking, records [50693].
[28/May/2024 12:05:25] "GET /web/assets/176874-d6fa3f9/web.report_assets_pdf.min.css HTTP/1.0" 200 - 4 0.001 0.004
[28/May/2024 12:05:25] "GET /web/assets/227768-c5247d9/web.report_assets_common.min.css HTTP/1.0" 404 - 2 0.002 0.004

We already set the report.url, web.base.url and web.base.url.freeze in the system parameters but this still happening randomly.

Thats sound like a problem with odoo.sh, so open a support ticket there. I don't think you've made a mistake. Or did you install custom modules?

We opened several support tickets but they always ask a way to reproduce the problem. Because this is happening randomly we don't have a way to reproduce it.

Ofcourse they ask because they need a way to debug or have an initial spot to look for. I would ask for the same. Is it possible to make a multi day log to give them?
